# Load a JSP in a foreground frame

Tags: html, jsp

I have two JSPs, one frontend and one backend.
The frontend jsp contains a few forms which are submitted to the backend jsp. The backend jsp processes these and redirects back to the frontend.

The body of the backend page contains a redirect message like 'Please wait' and redirects to frontend after a set timeout.

Currently this backend page is displayed once the user clicks submit and then redirected to frontend.

Is there a way to load this background page in some kind of a foreground container so that the frontend page remains as is and refreshes after the backend processing is complete.

The form submission is like this(Config.jsp):

```
<form id="Config" action="ConfigBackend.jsp" method=post>
some UI components....
     <input type="submit" name="Apply" value="Apply" />
</form>
```

Backend body is(ConfigBackend.jsp):

```
<body onload="setTimeout('Redirect()',200);">
</body>
```

Redirect function:

```
function Redirect() {
             location.href = 'Config.jsp';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I was too quick to ask!!

In any case the solution is to set the target of the form submit to a hidden iframe.